# How to Correct Anaconda Install Disabling USER accounts on openSUSE 42.3

Tags: anaconda, opensuse

I am using openSUSE 42.3 and I have found that installing anaconda as a user, i.e., in user home directory disables a subsequent login to that user by messing up dbus session processes.  Messages that appear upon login are related to dbus session manager not finding necessary files.  Login can not proceed.

Anaconda was installed following directly procedures on anaconda linux install pages.  Again, it was installed in a user directory.

After the first time the loss of user occurred, I found I could login to icewm desktop but was denied access to mate and gnome for the user.  I created another user in icewm and upon relogin the new user could login and mate and gnome which ran fine and I started over to transfer user processes to the new user which was laborious.  I could not login to my new user after I installed anaconda into the new user home.

By stroke of luck I found some others having problems with anaconda install affecting dbus sessions.  For an experiment, I commented out the line anaconda installs in .bashrc that contains the export to the anaconda bin files.  Upon doing that, I recovered use of both of my old users, i.e., they now logged into mate and gnome as they did originally.  Except now I have no anaconda.

I wish to know if others have had this problem.
I am seeking an explanation of the cause of this issue.
I am also seeking a means of installing anaconda as a user that does not replicate the process again.

Thanks for any ideas.
Tom Kosvic

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda ships its own version of the qt5 libraries.  Somehow the openSUSE distribution is set up in a way, that these qt5 libraries get precedence over the system qt5.  The issue is discussed at length [in the openSUSE forum](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/520628-Could-not-start-D-bus-Can-you-call-qdbus-qt5/page3) and in the [Anaconda bug-tracker](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1206), but this discussions mention explicitly the KDE / Plasma workspace.

So, yes, there appears to be a bug in openSUSE with respect to Anaconda, that should be reported in the openSUSE bugtracker: https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/

As a workaround, after your desktop has started, manually edit the `.bashrc` by un-commenting the line that the anaconda installer added.